# How can I create a tab control with Arabic content horizontally?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a tab control in WPF with Arabic content vertically but unfortunately  it shown vertically not in the horizontal orientation.

It works only with English content ( headers )

[image]

[image]

Code :

```
 <TabControl Width="100" Height="80" x:Name="tab" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    
                    <DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
```

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not issue of arabic language, but lenght of the words.

Remove

```
Width="100"
```

If you dont want it to be spread to full width, then set HorizontalAlignment like:

```
HorizontalAlignment ="Left"
```

Or

```
HorizontalAlignment ="Center"
```